# object has an extra property while extracting keys from an object

Tags: javascript

```
Object.prototype.looper = function() {
  var result = [];
  for (var property in this)
    result.push(property);
  return result;
};

var test = {name: "tab", age: 5};
console.log(test.looper());
```

How to eliminate looper to get just the keys

```
["name", "age", "looper", looper: function]
```

Output Needed

```
 ["name", "age"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two solutions. You could either use `Object.keys` which does the same thing your `looper` function does:

```
var test = {name: "tab", age: 5};
console.log(Object.keys(test));
```

The second way is to add an additional check `hasOwnProperty` to `looper`:

```
Object.prototype.looper = function() {
  var result = [];
  for (var property in this)
    if (this.hasOwnProperty(property))
      result.push(property);
  return result;
};

var test = {name: "tab", age: 5};
console.log(test.looper());
```

It's that simple. See the demos:

1. http://jsfiddle.net/aaditmshah/bhZbk/
2. http://jsfiddle.net/aaditmshah/bhZbk/1/

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method. This only gives you the enumerable keys, so you won't be getting the looper key.

```
// Enumerable keys as an array
Object.keys( objectName );
```

The Object.keys method is included in the latest browsers, and you can add it in older browser if it doesn't exist, as mentioned in the linked article.

Answer (score 1):

[hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) does the trick:

```
for (var property in this) {
    if (this.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        result.push(property);
    }
}
```

`for..in` iterates all properties in the prototype chain, hence it's recommended to always use `hasOwnProperty()` check when iterating properties of an object, especially when using some libraries. This is also one reason, why `for..in` is not suitable to iterate arrays.